# Is my graph correct?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

My problem told me that:

Let $S$ be the surface described by the equation in cylindrical coordinates
$z = r^2$, and the inequality $0 ≤ z ≤ 4$, oriented such that the unit normal vector points downwards.

It won't let me upload my photo, but it's a paraboloid that points upwards. It's a v-shaped cylinder, with a rounded bottom, and a height of $4$. So if my unit normal vector points downwards the orientation will be clockwise?
Also, if it asks me to describe $\partial S$, is that just the surface part, which looks like an oval?